# Problems with the video slider

Tags: javascript, video

Hi i've added a simple function to my javascript that pauses the video when the slider handle is being dragged and unpauses it when released(this happens if the video is playing and it works properly).If the video is paused instead, when the slider handle is released i want the video to remain paused(this is the part that doesn't work) . The problem i've encountered is that after i release the slider handler it resumes playing. I've tried working around the problem with a variable but it doesn't seem to work. Here is the code:

js:

```
// Pause the video when the slider handle is being dragged
var control=0;
seekslider.addEventListener("mousedown", function() {

    if(video.pause==true)
    {
        control=1;

    }
    else {
        video.pause();
    }

        });

    // Play the video when the slider handle is dropped
seekslider.addEventListener("mouseup", function() {

        if(control>0)
        {
            control=0;
        }
        else
        {
            video.play();

        }
        });
```

Comment: do not think after control=0 you need to pause again ?? `control=0;video.pause();`

Comment: well it should already be paused because otherwise control would not be >0

Comment: You can check video.paused to see if it's paused, no need for another variable.

Comment: Ok! but after that you not check for it? do you set interval?@Patratel

Comment: the variable is there to store that the video was already paused and it was not done so by the event mousedown so it should not be resumed

Answer (score 0):

Add this one more Function

```
function seektimeupdate(){
    var nt = video.currentTime * (100 / video.duration);
    seekslider.value = nt;
}
```

Comment: i already have that function but it's not related to the problem i think